# Запуск функции JS по нажатию на <button>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу разобраться, как можно сделать так, чтобы таймер запускался по нажатию на кнопку, а не при загрузке страницы? Заранее спасибо.

```js
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "countdown360",
    defaults = {
      radius: 15.5, // radius of arc
      strokeStyle: "#0081d7", // the color of the stroke
      strokeWidth: 5, // the stroke width, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fillStyle: "#004388", // the fill color
      fontColor: "#477050", // the font color
      fontFamily: "sans-serif", // the font family
      fontSize: 15, // the font size, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fontWeight: 200, // the font weight
      autostart: false, // start the countdown automatically
      seconds: 10, // the number of seconds to count down
      label: ["second", "seconds"], // the label to use or false if none
      startOverAfterAdding: true, // Start the timer over after time is added with addSeconds
      smooth: false, // should the timer be smooth or stepping
      onComplete: function() {}
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (!this.settings.fontSize) {
      this.settings.fontSize = this.settings.radius / 1.2;
    }
    if (!this.settings.strokeWidth) {
      this.settings.strokeWidth = this.settings.radius / 4;
    }
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    getTimeRemaining: function() {

      var timeRemaining = this._secondsLeft(this.getElapsedTime());
      return timeRemaining;
    },
    getElapsedTime: function() {
      return Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
    },
    extendTimer: function(value) {
      var seconds = parseInt(value),
        secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if ((this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + seconds) <= this.settings.seconds) {
        this.startedAt.setSeconds(this.startedAt.getSeconds() + parseInt(value));
      }
    },

    addSeconds: function(value) {
      var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if (this.settings.startOverAfterAdding) {
        this.settings.seconds = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + parseInt(value);
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.settings.seconds += parseInt(value);
      }
    },

    start: function() {
      this.startedAt = new Date();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, true);
      this._drawCountdownLabel(0);
      var timerInterval = 1000;
      if (this.settings.smooth) {
        timerInterval = 16;
      }
      this.interval = setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw, this), timerInterval);
    },

    stop: function(cb) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (cb) {
        cb();
      }
    },

    _init: function() {
      this.settings.width = (this.settings.radius * 2) + (this.settings.strokeWidth * 2);
      this.settings.height = this.settings.width;
      this.settings.arcX = this.settings.radius + this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.settings.arcY = this.settings.arcX;
      this._initPen(this._getCanvas());
      if (this.settings.autostart) {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    _getCanvas: function() {
      var $canvas = $("<canvas id=\"countdown360_" + $(this.element).attr("id") + "\" width=\"" +
        this.settings.width + "\" height=\"" +
        this.settings.height + "\">" +
        "<span id=\"countdown-text\" role=\"status\" aria-live=\"assertive\"></span></canvas>");
      $(this.element).prepend($canvas[0]);
      return $canvas[0];
    },

    _initPen: function(canvas) {
      this.pen = canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.pen.lineWidth = this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.pen.strokeStyle = this.settings.strokeStyle;
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.textAlign = "center";
      this.pen.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ariaText = $(canvas).children("#countdown-text");
      this._clearRect();
    },

    _clearRect: function() {
      this.pen.clearRect(0, 0, this.settings.width, this.settings.height);
    },

    _secondsLeft: function(secondsElapsed) {
      return this.settings.seconds - secondsElapsed;
    },

    _drawCountdownLabel: function(secondsElapsed) {
      this.ariaText.text(secondsLeft);
      this.pen.font = this.settings.fontWeight + " " + this.settings.fontSize + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
      var secondsLeft = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed),
        label = secondsLeft === 1 ? this.settings.label[0] : this.settings.label[1],
        drawLabel = this.settings.label && this.settings.label.length === 2,
        x = this.settings.width / 2;
      if (drawLabel) {
        y = this.settings.height / 2 - (this.settings.fontSize / 6.2);
      } else {
        y = this.settings.height / 2;
      }
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft + 1, x, y);
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fontColor;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft, x, y);
      if (drawLabel) {
        this.pen.font = "normal small-caps " + (this.settings.fontSize / 3) + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
        this.pen.fillText(label, this.settings.width / 2, this.settings.height / 2 + (this.settings.fontSize / 0.0));
      }
    },

    _drawCountdownShape: function(endAngle, drawStroke) {
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.beginPath();
      this.pen.arc(this.settings.arcX, this.settings.arcY, this.settings.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, endAngle, false);
      this.pen.fill();
      if (drawStroke) {
        this.pen.stroke();
      }
    },

    _draw: function() {
      var millisElapsed, secondsElapsed;
      millisElapsed = new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime();
      secondsElapsed = Math.floor((millisElapsed) / 1000);
      endAngle = (Math.PI * 3.5) - (((Math.PI * 2) / (this.settings.seconds * 1000)) * millisElapsed);
      this._clearRect();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, false);
      if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
        this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
        this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
      } else {
        this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
        this.stop();
        this.settings.onComplete();
      }
    }

  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    var plugin;
    this.each(function() {
      plugin = $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
      if (!plugin) {
        plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, plugin);
      }
    });
    return plugin;
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);

var cdLength = $('.countdown').length; // кол-во таймеров
var cdCount = 1; // счетчик таймеров
var cdOptions = { // настройки таймеров
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 5,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',
  autostart: true,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log(cdCount + ' done');
    cdCount = cdCount + 1; // прибавляем к счетчику 1, чтобы получить следующий номер таймера
    if (cdCount <= cdLength) { // если номер таймера <= общему кол-ву таймеров
      $('#countdown' + cdCount).countdown360(cdOptions); // запускаем следующий таймер
    }
  }
};
$('#countdown' + cdCount).countdown360(cdOptions); // запуск первого таймера
```

```css
<style>
.w3-button {width:160px;}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

  <p><button class="w3-button w3-blue">START</button></p>
  

What can you tell me about yourself?
<div id="countdown1" class="countdown"></div>
Can you list your strengths?
<div id="countdown2" class="countdown"></div>
What weaknesses do you have?
<div id="countdown3" class="countdown"></div>
Where do you see yourself five years from now?
<div id="countdown4" class="countdown"></div>
Why do you want to work here?
<div id="countdown5" class="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: autostart:true в настройках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках таймеров пропишите `autostart:false` и по клику активируйте первый таймер методом `.start()`:

```js
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "countdown360",
    defaults = {
      radius: 15.5, // radius of arc
      strokeStyle: "#0081d7", // the color of the stroke
      strokeWidth: 5, // the stroke width, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fillStyle: "#004388", // the fill color
      fontColor: "#477050", // the font color
      fontFamily: "sans-serif", // the font family
      fontSize: 15, // the font size, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fontWeight: 200, // the font weight
      autostart: false, // start the countdown automatically
      seconds: 10, // the number of seconds to count down
      label: ["second", "seconds"], // the label to use or false if none
      startOverAfterAdding: true, // Start the timer over after time is added with addSeconds
      smooth: false, // should the timer be smooth or stepping
      onComplete: function() {}
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (!this.settings.fontSize) {
      this.settings.fontSize = this.settings.radius / 1.2;
    }
    if (!this.settings.strokeWidth) {
      this.settings.strokeWidth = this.settings.radius / 4;
    }
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    getTimeRemaining: function() {

      var timeRemaining = this._secondsLeft(this.getElapsedTime());
      return timeRemaining;
    },
    getElapsedTime: function() {
      return Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
    },
    extendTimer: function(value) {
      var seconds = parseInt(value),
        secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if ((this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + seconds) <= this.settings.seconds) {
        this.startedAt.setSeconds(this.startedAt.getSeconds() + parseInt(value));
      }
    },

    addSeconds: function(value) {
      var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if (this.settings.startOverAfterAdding) {
        this.settings.seconds = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + parseInt(value);
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.settings.seconds += parseInt(value);
      }
    },

    start: function() {
      this.startedAt = new Date();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, true);
      this._drawCountdownLabel(0);
      var timerInterval = 1000;
      if (this.settings.smooth) {
        timerInterval = 16;
      }
      this.interval = setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw, this), timerInterval);
    },

    stop: function(cb) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (cb) {
        cb();
      }
    },

    _init: function() {
      this.settings.width = (this.settings.radius * 2) + (this.settings.strokeWidth * 2);
      this.settings.height = this.settings.width;
      this.settings.arcX = this.settings.radius + this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.settings.arcY = this.settings.arcX;
      this._initPen(this._getCanvas());
      if (this.settings.autostart) {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    _getCanvas: function() {
      var $canvas = $("<canvas id=\"countdown360_" + $(this.element).attr("id") + "\" width=\"" +
        this.settings.width + "\" height=\"" +
        this.settings.height + "\">" +
        "<span id=\"countdown-text\" role=\"status\" aria-live=\"assertive\"></span></canvas>");
      $(this.element).prepend($canvas[0]);
      return $canvas[0];
    },

    _initPen: function(canvas) {
      this.pen = canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.pen.lineWidth = this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.pen.strokeStyle = this.settings.strokeStyle;
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.textAlign = "center";
      this.pen.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ariaText = $(canvas).children("#countdown-text");
      this._clearRect();
    },

    _clearRect: function() {
      this.pen.clearRect(0, 0, this.settings.width, this.settings.height);
    },

    _secondsLeft: function(secondsElapsed) {
      return this.settings.seconds - secondsElapsed;
    },

    _drawCountdownLabel: function(secondsElapsed) {
      this.ariaText.text(secondsLeft);
      this.pen.font = this.settings.fontWeight + " " + this.settings.fontSize + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
      var secondsLeft = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed),
        label = secondsLeft === 1 ? this.settings.label[0] : this.settings.label[1],
        drawLabel = this.settings.label && this.settings.label.length === 2,
        x = this.settings.width / 2;
      if (drawLabel) {
        y = this.settings.height / 2 - (this.settings.fontSize / 6.2);
      } else {
        y = this.settings.height / 2;
      }
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft + 1, x, y);
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fontColor;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft, x, y);
      if (drawLabel) {
        this.pen.font = "normal small-caps " + (this.settings.fontSize / 3) + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
        this.pen.fillText(label, this.settings.width / 2, this.settings.height / 2 + (this.settings.fontSize / 0.0));
      }
    },

    _drawCountdownShape: function(endAngle, drawStroke) {
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.beginPath();
      this.pen.arc(this.settings.arcX, this.settings.arcY, this.settings.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, endAngle, false);
      this.pen.fill();
      if (drawStroke) {
        this.pen.stroke();
      }
    },

    _draw: function() {
      var millisElapsed, secondsElapsed;
      millisElapsed = new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime();
      secondsElapsed = Math.floor((millisElapsed) / 1000);
      endAngle = (Math.PI * 3.5) - (((Math.PI * 2) / (this.settings.seconds * 1000)) * millisElapsed);
      this._clearRect();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, false);
      if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
        this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
        this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
      } else {
        this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
        this.stop();
        this.settings.onComplete();
      }
    }

  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    var plugin;
    this.each(function() {
      plugin = $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
      if (!plugin) {
        plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, plugin);
      }
    });
    return plugin;
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);

var cdLength = $('.countdown').length; // кол-во таймеров
var cdCount = 1; // счетчик таймеров
let cdOptions = { // настройки таймеров
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 5,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',
  autostart: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log(cdCount + ' done');
    cdCount = cdCount + 1; // прибавляем к счетчику 1, чтобы получить следующий номер таймера
    if (cdCount <= cdLength) { // если номер таймера <= общему кол-ву таймеров
      $('#countdown' + cdCount).countdown360(cdOptions).start(); // запускаем следующий таймер
    }
  }
};
$('.w3-button').on('click', function() {
  $('#countdown' + cdCount).countdown360(cdOptions).start();
});
```

```css
<style>.w3-button {
  width: 160px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<p><button class="w3-button w3-blue">START</button></p>


What can you tell me about yourself?
<div id="countdown1" class="countdown"></div>
Can you list your strengths?
<div id="countdown2" class="countdown"></div>
What weaknesses do you have?
<div id="countdown3" class="countdown"></div>
Where do you see yourself five years from now?
<div id="countdown4" class="countdown"></div>
Why do you want to work here?
<div id="countdown5" class="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, приятно что все доходчиво объясняете. 5+

Answer (score 0):

Это jQuery

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  ваш код для работы счётчика
}
```

,или [onclick()](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onclick)
на javaScript